# perl: how to sort a JSON structure on something other than "root" key attributes

Tags: perl, json, sorting

Perl: 
How can I sort a complex structure using JSON::PP ?

From the JSON Documentation:

> As the sorting routine runs in the
>   JSON::PP scope, the given subroutine
>   name and the special variables $a, $b
>   will begin 'JSON::PP::'.

Here is my attempt, does not seem to work

```
open my $fh, ">", $file or warn " exportAsJSON: can't open file: '$file': $!";
print $fh  $coder->sort_by(sub {$_->{column_def}->{$JSON::PP::a} cmp $_->{column_def}->{$JSON::PP::b}  } )->encode(\%json);
close $fh;
```

I want to sort by key, then the column_def attribute on the attribute key below "column_def", i.e. 
density, depth_in_m, mag_sus
:

```
{
    "column_def":
        {
            "depth_in_m":
                {
                    "names":"depth_in_m",
                    "pos":"0"
                },
            "mag_sus":
                {
                    "names":
                        {
                            "A_ALIAS":"Mag-Sus.",
                            "A_DESC":"magnetic susceptibility in SI",
                            "ATTRIBUTE":"MAG_SUS"
                        },
                    "pos":"2"
                },
            "density":
                {
                    "names":
                        {
                            "A_ALIAS":"Density",
                            "A_DESC":"density in gm\/cc",
                            "ATTRIBUTE":"DENSITY"
                        },
                    "pos":"1"
                }
        },
    "data":
        {
            "depth_in_m":"14.635",
            "mag_sus":"n.a.",
            "density":"n.a."
        }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious to know why you're sorting something that will parse to a hash - which has no inherent ordering.

Comment: @Bears will eat you: indeed, the in-memory representation has no inherent ordering. I want to save the sorted hash-structure to a file (or tempfile), for diff'ing and visual inspection (and more complicated things afterwards).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not certain I understand how you want the JSON output to be sorted -- aside from sorting by hash key. If that's all you want, just pass the `canonical` method a true argument.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON::PP;

# A simple hash-of-hashes for exploration.
my $h = {
    Z => { c => 1, d => 2 },
    A => { a => 3, r => 4 },
    B => { c => 5, x => 6 },
    S => { q => 7, d => 8 },
};

my $js = JSON::PP->new;
$js->canonical(1);

my $output = $js->encode($h);
print $output;
```

If you do use the `sort_by` method, it does not make sense to use `$_` within the `sort` block: what would it represent? It was not clear from the documentation what arguments the `sort_by` code will receive. Using `Data::Dumper` like this:

```
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

my $sorter = sub {
    # See what's going on.
    print "$JSON::PP::a cmp $JSON::PP::b\n";
    print Dumper(\@_, $_);
    <STDIN>;

    # Sort hash keys alphabetically.
    $JSON::PP::a cmp $JSON::PP::b;
};

my $output = $js->sort_by($sorter)->encode($h);
```

You can infer that `sort_by` works like this: (1) it receives two arguments, the `JSON::PP` object and the hash ref currently being worked with; and (2) the `$JSON::PP::a` and `$JSON::PP::b` variables hold the hash keys being compared. **But note** that the hash ref refers to the JSON output as it is being built from the leaf nodes upward. It does not refer to your original data structure. This would seem to make the task of writing a comparator a bit trickier. Good luck.

```
my $sorter = sub {
    my ($json_pp_object, $hash_ref) = @_;

    # Write your own comparator here.
};

my $output = $js->sort_by($sorter)->encode($h);
```

Comment: Intended sorting: 
First alphabetically by hash key,  
Second alphabetically by first hashref subkey. 

Maybe alternatively,(second),  numerically by value of "pos"  (after figuring out how sorting works on nested structures).

Comment: Personal note: This is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041762/iterating-over-a-javascript-object-in-sort-order-based-on-particular-key-value-of

Comment: A note while writing your own sorter. It appears $JSON::PP::VERSION = '2.27200' doesn't give the JSON::PP object as a first argument. For your last example, the sorter on version >= 2.27200 would need to use my $hashref = shift;