# Get element of JS object with an index

Tags: javascript, object

Ok so let's say that I have my object

```
myobj = {"A":["Abe"], "B":["Bob"]}
```

and I want to get the first element out of it. As in I want it to return `Abe` which has an index of `A`. How can I do something along the lines of `myobj[0]` and get out "Abe".

Comment: You can't, reliably; there's no guarantee of the order of the properties stored in an object.

Comment: Can you construct an example that isn't ambiguous? Which `B` is important here?

Comment: I constructed the example the way it should have been written.

Answer (score 115):

I know it's a late answer, but I think this is what OP asked for.

```
myobj[Object.keys(myobj)[0]];
```

Comment: "The ordering of the properties is the same as that given by looping over the properties of the object manually." as shown in this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: For anyone that is going to use this please keep in mind that not all browsers support Object.keys. See here -  http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#test-Object.keys . MDN also provides a ployfill for this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys.

Answer (score 26):

JS objects have no defined order, they are (by definition) an *unsorted* set of key-value pairs.

If by "first" you mean "first in lexicographical order", you can however use:

```
var sortedKeys = Object.keys(myobj).sort();
```

and then use:

```
var first = myobj[sortedKeys[0]];
```

Answer (score 14):

```
myobj = {"A":["Abe"], "B":["Bob"]}

Object.keys(myobj)[0];  //return the key name at index 0
Object.values(myobj)[0]  //return the key values at index 0
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try

```js
    Object.entries(myobj)[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var myobj = {"A":["Abe"], "B":["Bob"]};

var keysArray = Object.keys(myobj);

var valuesArray = Object.keys(myobj).map(function(k) {

   return String(myobj[k]);

});

var mydata = valuesArray[keysArray.indexOf("A")]; // Abe
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myobj.A
```

------- or ----------

```
myobj['A']
```

will get you 'B'

Comment: But the OP's point is that the property name `A` isn't known.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(myobj, function(index, value) { 
    console.log(myobj[index]);
});
```

Comment: You switched the closing bracket and curly brace !

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
const obj = {
    name: 'John Doe',
    age: 34,
    country: 'Switzerland',
};

var _key = Object.keys(obj)[0]
var _value = Object.values(obj)[0]
var key = Object.entries(obj)[0][0]
var value = Object.entries(obj)[0][1]

console.log(_key)
console.log(_value)
console.log(key)
console.log(value)
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want a specific order, then you must use an array, not an object.  Objects do not have a defined order.

For example, using an array, you could do this:

```
var myobj = [{"A":["B"]}, {"B": ["C"]}];
var firstItem = myobj[0];
```

Then, you can use myobj[0] to get the first object in the array.

Or, depending upon what you're trying to do:

```
var myobj = [{key: "A", val:["B"]}, {key: "B",  val:["C"]}];
var firstKey = myobj[0].key;   // "A"
var firstValue = myobj[0].val; // "["B"]
```