# Find the value of a property in an object by the order they are assigned

Tags: javascript, object

In an array you can find the fifth value by:

```
array[4]
```

But can you do the same for objects?
For example if I have:

```
test =
{
    tree: "epic",
    town: "cool",
    airport: "yay",
}
```

And then I want to use airport by its number, 3, how do I do that?

Comment: Object properties have no ordering. The language spec doesn't require that the runtime produce property names in any particular order, in other words. So, no, not without keeping track of some ordering yourself.

Comment: there is no order in key, value pairs, so no you cannot do what you mentioned. However you can design your array to be like test = [{tree: epic}, {town: cool} ...]

Comment: which number has airport? do you have some code to show?

Comment: @Rash: That makes it difficult because you still need to use the correct property name at the correct index. If there's to be a required order, a second array with just the property names as strings is better. `props = ["tree", "town", "airport"]` then `test[props[2]]`

Comment: Ok thanks guys, I know that it doesnt work now.

Comment: You can actually find them by index. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31103463/3257901) on the original question.