# Structure of the JSON and HTML for a complex dynamic table

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, servicenow

**My Requirement:** - (I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kainikhil/0h8y1grj/3/) with my current progress)

I have an angular[1.4.0] app where I need to populate a table & its content **dynamically** including the header names and their corresponding values using a json object being sent from the backend(ServiceNow).

As of now, the table looks something like as shown below
[image]

As you can see above, using `ng-repeat` the headers(Users, Required Headset etc) are being iterated from the object horizontally/column-wise(`<th>`) AND the User column(left most) are also being iterated dynamically vertically/row-wise(`<tr>`). **The 'User' header will always be the only known first column but its values will be again dynamic**.

Next, the elements that come under each header are also unknown/dynamic, meaning whether the elements under "Required Headset" column should be a selectbox/textbox/checkbox is determined by the data coming from the backend.

Also I obviously need to control these elements individually which means I need unique `ng-model` for each dynamic field which could be achieved with the prototype method but in this complex case I'm not sure how.

> So basically, the number of users should determine the number of rows and each row will have varied inputs/elements for each columns. Later the consumer enters the values in the fields and saves the updated data.

**My Question:**

What is the best way to structure the JSON and correspondingly iterate the items in the HTML to get the above requirements.

**What I have done so far:**

Since the Users are iterating row-wise different from others being iterated column-wise(header names and their corresponding elements which come under it), I created 2 objects ie, `$scope.users` which is an Array and `$scope.rowData` which is an Array of objects containing column-wise details which looks like below.

```
$scope.rowData = [
{
   column_name: "Required Headset",
   options: ["one", "two", "three"],
   required: "true",
   type: "select",
   u_req_headset: ""
},
{
   column_name: "Primary Contact Number",
   options: [],
   required: "true",
   type: "text",
   u_primary_contact_number: ""
}
...
];
```

PS: In this object I tried to create unique keys(`u_req_headset` and `u_primary_contact_number`) so I can use them in `ng-model` to later get the updated field values but currently not able to get it to work.

Using the above objects, in HTML I am iterating these as shown below

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>User</th>
            <th ng-repeat="m in rowData">
                {{m.column_name}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users track by $index">
            <td>{{user}}</td>
            <td ng-repeat="row in rowData track by $index">
                <input ng-if="row.type == 'text'" type="text" />

                <input type="checkbox" ng-if="row.type == 'checkbox'"/>

                <select ng-if="row.type == 'select'">
                    <option ng-repeat="option in row.options" value="{{option}}">{{option}}</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Issue I am facing, where I would appreciate any help:**

With the current solution, the issues I am facing are:(1st being the most important)

- Way to bind values of each fields uniquely to get each fields value on save. Obviously if I use `ng-model="something"`, the change would reflect for all the rows & this is obviously wrong in many levels. I need to use the prototype way, eg: `row.u_req_headset` from the above object but the issue again is key name( "u_req_headset" in this case) is not static. It can be something very different for another table data(dynamic). **I just need a variable to bind each element individually within `ng-repeat` so I can get the value of that element later on save**
- Soon I am also planning to add validations to these dynamic fields.
- I am sure there is a better way to structure the json and populate the data for my requirement.

The explanation might be a little complex or confusing but unfortunately so is my requirement so I have created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kainikhil/0h8y1grj/3/) to replicate my current situation. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it wasn't working was because the model you were using was 'row.answer', which is the same for all iterations against 'users'.

Fixed the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0h8y1grj/5/).

```html
<tr ng-repeat="user in users">
  <td>{{user.name}}</td>
  <td ng-repeat="row in rowData">
    <input ng-model="user.answer" ng-if="row.type == 'text'" type="text" />

    <input ng-model="user.check" type="checkbox" ng-if="row.type == 'checkbox'" />

    <select ng-model="user.selected" ng-if="row.type == 'select'">
      <option ng-repeat="option in row.options" value="{{option}}">{{option}}</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Never thought of it that wat. Thanks for the help Abdullah.

Comment: Also can I please ask how can I use a non-predefined variable for a model - say I want to use only the 2nd key in the object no matter what that model name is? (since the key names are dynamic & hence cannot use them directly) Check the object values in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kainikhil/0h8y1grj/6/).

Comment: Because I was wondering with your solution, what if a row has more than 1 text box then both will have the same models in a row.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you're looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044845/retrieving-a-property-of-a-json-object-by-index).

Comment: I have tried `obj[Object.keys(obj)[1]]` but somehow not got it working inside `ng-model` directive. Something like `ng-model="user[Object.keys(user)[1]]"` from [your solution](http://jsfiddle.net/kainikhil/0h8y1grj/6/) but it returns `undefined`. Any idea how to get that javascript code working inside `ng-model`

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit confused with your question but i assume you need this.

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users track by $index">

     <td>{{user}}</td>

     <td ng-repeat="row in rowData track by $index">

        <input ng-if="row.type == 'text'" type="text" ng-model="row.answer"/>

        <input type="checkbox" ng-if="row.type == 'checkbox'" ng-model="row.answer"/>

        <select ng-if="row.type == 'select'" ng-model="row.answer">
         <option ng-repeat="option in row.options" value="{{option}}">{{option}}</option>
        </select>

    </td>
</tr>
```

So what happens here is, you original object $scope.rowData gets modified with user provided answer like this:

```
    [{
        column_name: "Required Headset",
        options: ["one", "two", "three"],
        required: "true",
        type: "select",
        u_req_headset: "",
        answer: "answer1"
    }, {
        column_name: "Primary Contact Number",
        options: [],
        required: "true",
        type: "text",
        u_primary_contact_number: "",
        answer: "answer2"
    }];
```

Comment: I tried this already. If i do this to say `type="text"` field, then that textbox in all the iterated rows gets affected simultaneously. Meaning if I type "something" in one of the textbox, then all the textbox in that column will have "something". Also I don't want the value to come as a placeholder. **I just need a variable to bind each element individually within an `ng-repeat`** so I can get the value of that element later on save.

Comment: You can see what I mean in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kainikhil/0h8y1grj/2/)

Comment: Hi nikhil. after seeing your fiddle, i understood the exact issue. AbdullahTariq has given perfect solution to you. you just need to change users array to json array and ng-model.

Comment: Hi @ni3aj - Yes, that seems to do the trick. Thanks a lot for the help