# Retrieving Mixpanel data from JSON in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json

I am trying to get data from a Mixpanel API. The JSON result looks like this:

```
{"computed_at": "2019-11-19T10:36:33.908802+00:00", "legend_size": 1, "data": {"series": ["2019-11-11", "2019-11-12", "2019-11-13"], "values": {"page views": {"2019-11-12": 111, "2019-11-11": 573, "2019-11-13": 209}}}}
```

I am struggling with nested JSON (despite looking at a fair few StackOverflow articles on this) and I want to try and get the values `111`,`573` and `209` for the page views. How do I access these values?

I've tried the following:

```
var result = {"computed_at": "2019-11-19T10:36:33.908802+00:00", "legend_size": 1, "data": {"series": ["2019-11-11", "2019-11-12", "2019-11-13"], "values": {"page views": {"2019-11-12": 111, "2019-11-11": 573, "2019-11-13": 209}}}}
var rawData = result["data"]["values"]["page views"][0]
```

but this doesn't work and I can't figure out how to access the individual values. Can anyone help please?

EDIT:

When using the json to C# converter (as suggested in the comments to this post) the outcome is as follows:

```
public class PageViews
{
    public int __invalid_name__2019-11-20 { get; set; }
    public int __invalid_name__2019-11-19 { get; set; }
}

public class Values
{
    public PageViews __invalid_name__page views { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public List<string> series { get; set; }
    public Values values { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public DateTime computed_at { get; set; }
    public int legend_size { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

and I am still unsure how to get the numbers from this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches you could take. First, I'd deserialize the json string using [this library - Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

You can then go through the json using JObjects, or you can create a C#-Class that represents your json data and then deserialize it into a corresponding object.

1. Via a class:

To create the json class there is this website, which creates the classes (also nested) just as the json needs them to be: http://json2csharp.com/

Then you use:

```
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(jsonString);
```

and then simply go through your object properties.

2. Via JObject

JObjects allow you to search through the json string easily as such:

```
JObject myObject = JObject.Parse(json);

var results = myObject["data"]["values"]["page views"].First();
```

**Edit:**
Since your Json contains keys, which begin with a number (and are not valid c# variable names) its a bit more tricky but doable. The automatic converter failed on this.

```
  string json = "{\"computed_at\": \"2019 - 11 - 19T10: 36:33.908802 + 00:00\", \"legend_size\": 1, \"data\": {\"series\": [\"2019 - 11 - 11\", \"2019 - 11 - 12\", \"2019 - 11 - 13\"], \"values\": {\"page views\": {\"2019 - 11 - 12\": 111, \"2019 - 11 - 11\": 573, \"2019 - 11 - 13\": 209}}}}";

  var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

  foreach (var view in myObject.data.series)
  {
     int number = myObject.data.values.page_views[view];
     Console.WriteLine($"{number} views on {view}");
  }
```

With the `RootObject` class being:

```
 public class Values
{
    [JsonProperty("page views")]
    public Dictionary<string, int> page_views { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public List<string> series { get; set; }
    public Values values { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string computed_at { get; set; }
    public int legend_size { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

The trick was to use a `Dictionary<string, int>` type for the date-values, and rename the property to a valid c# name. The JsonDeserializer still finds the data, because we told it to look for "page views" using the `JsonProperty` attribute. This way the class is also flexible for multiple entries in your "page views" field.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks so much @Luchspeter this is really useful. I'd like to go down the first route and create a C# class and deserialize it into a corresponding object. However, the conversion converts into lots of classes and I'm still not sure how to access the numbers from this? I have edited my original question showing this.

Comment: Ok I'll have a look at it.
The reason is, that your json contains parameter names, that are not valid c# variable names. In c# a variable cannot start with a number. There are ways to work around this, and I'll go through them and edit the answer

Comment: thank you so much for your time and explanation with this - this really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You were close. In the line

`var rawData = result["data"]["values"]["page views"][0]`

you are attempting to access index 0 of an object. This doesn't really make sense because objects are basically dictionaries or hash tables, which means they are unordered and must be accessed by a key rather than an index (See [Retrieving a property of a JSON object by index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044845/retrieving-a-property-of-a-json-object-by-index)).

What you want looks like

`var rawData = result["data"]["values"]["page views"]['2019-11-12']` to access the number of page views (which is `111`) for the date `2019-11-12`.

You can then loop through the object and get each number of page views as follows:

```
var pageViews = [];
for (var key of Object.keys(result.data.values['page views'])) {
    pageViews.push(result.data.values['page views'][key]);
}
```