# Building ordered JSON in perl

Tags: json, perl, d3.js

I'm having a bit of a fiddle with JSON and D3, trying to represent some disk usage information in a 'bubble' style.

Based on this initially: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269

The JSON is pretty simple - hierarchical data looking a bit like this:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4063530/flare.json

```
{
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
      {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Now, what I'm *trying* to do is take a `quotas` report from a NetApp - in XML form.

I have multiple 'per server' XML files looking approximately like:

```
<quotas>
  <quota>
    <quota-target>/vol/vol1/qtree1</quota-target>
    <volume>vol1</volume>
    <disk-used>554444</disk-used>
    <disk-limit>2000000</disk-limit>
  </quota>
  <quota>
    <quota-target>/vol/vol1/qtree2</quota-target>
    <volume>vol1</volume>
    <disk-used>1235655</disk-used>
    <disk-limit>2000000</disk-limit>
  </quota>
  <quota>
    <quota-target>/vol/vol2/qtree1</quota-target>
    <volume>vol2</volume>
    <disk-used>987664</disk-used>
    <disk-limit>2000000</disk-limit>
  </quota>
</quotas>
```

What I'm trying to do is assemble some JSON for use with D3 that's hierarchical:

- site
- server
- volume
- quota-target
- disk-used

I'm doing ok with a foreach loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;
use JSON;

my %sites = (
    'site1' => [qw ( servera serverb )],
    'site2' => [qw ( s2serverc s2serverd)],
);

my $data;
$data->{'name'} = "quotas";
foreach my $sitename ( keys %sites ) {
    my $site = { 'name' => $sitename };
    push( @{ $data->{'children'} }, $site );
    foreach my $server ( @{ $sites{$sitename} } ) {
        my $server = { 'name' => $server };
        push( @{ $site->{'children'} }, $server );

        $twig->parsefile("$server.quotas.xml");
        foreach my $quota ( $twig->get_xpath('//quota') ) {
            push(
                @{ $server->{'children'} },
                {   'name' => $quota->first_child_text('quota-target'),
                    'size' => $quota->first_child_text('disk-used')
                }
                )

        }
    }
}

open( my $output, ">", "quotas.json" ) or die $!;
print {$output} to_json( $data, { 'pretty' => 1 } );
close($output);
```

This is broadly working, and producing me pretty pictures.

However I'm having two problems:

Ordering of the JSON changes each run, because I'm using a hash. Whilst not a show stopper - is there a way I can enforce an order in the JSON output? (Not necessarily just 'sorted' alphabetically)

Similarly - I'm looking at how to insert a 'volume' level node which isn't currently present, as I'm creating new anonymous hashes to insert into `children` at each layer of the `foreach` loop. This feels a bit clunky, but what I'm thinking is:

- Extract a list of volumes with `get_xpath('//volume')` and uniqueify it.
- Either iterate `per volume` finding subnodes that match (Is there an `xpath` expression to specify a child value?)
- Or create a 'staging' hash of hashes that I then 'merge' into `children` in the JSON.

Does anyone have any better suggestions?

I can quite easily create a hash of the desired structure e.g.

```
$stuff{$site}{$server}{$volume}{$qtree} = $size;
```

But then would have to turn that into the appropriate JSON (which I suppose might be a better approach overall).

Comment: Your Question seems to contain more than one question.

Answer (score 1):

> *is there a way I can enforce an order in the JSON output?*

Yeah, use an array instead of an object. JSON objects are unordered.

> An *object* is an unordered set of name/value pairs.

But it seems you're already using arrays for your lists.

Maybe you're want to be able to perform diffs, in which case JSON.pm provides a coarse means of specifying keys in the form of `sort_by`. Useful if you want to perform diffs.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to "enforce" some sorting by the hash key, you can use the "canonical" feature, as also said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532067/perl-how-to-sort-a-json-structure-on-something-other-than-root-key-attributes).